# GoalSeek inside loop - Run time error 1004 : Reference is not valid

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm writing a code which goes into different sheets and performs `GoalSeek` on rows that have the word "Obj" and "Var". After completing my first sheet, the code moves on to the second sheet and prompted the `error 1004`. It says my reference for the `Do ... Loop` function is no longer valid. Why could that be?

```
Sub GoalSeek()  

Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim SecondAddress As String
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim y As Long
Dim i As Long

Arr = Array("SheetA", "SheetB")

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)

    With Worksheets(Arr(i)).Range("A1:BZ500")

    Set Rng = .Find("Obj", LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

        FirstAddress = Rng.Address

        Set Rng2 = .Find("Var", LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not Rng2 Is Nothing Then

            SecondAddress = Rng2.Address

            'Error Occurred Here
            Do

                Rng.Offset(0, y + 1).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Rng2.Offset(0, y + 1)

                y = y + 1

            Loop Until y = 12

        End If

    End If

    End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Means there's a anomaly... Many possible reasons. i.e. the goalseeking range does not have a formula, its formula does not depend on the  `ChangingCell`, the latter was empty, formula too complicated, the calculation failed to find a solution, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be your issue:

You initialise `y` at the beginning,

```
dim y as long
```

and by default it has the value `0`. You make this assumption during your loop

```
Do
    Rng.Offset(0, y + 1).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Rng2.Offset(0, y + 1)
    y = y + 1
Loop Until y = 12
```

For the first sheet, `y=0,1,2,3,...,12` then the loop stops. **Then you leave `y=12`** and move onto your next sheet.

So for the second sheet you go into the `Do` loop with `y=12` and get an error. You should amend your code to the following:

```
y = 0
Do
    Rng.Offset(0, y + 1).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Rng2.Offset(0, y + 1)
    y = y + 1
Loop Until y = 12
```

If you'd used a `Do While ... Loop` instead, you would probably have noticed this sooner because the loop would never even have been entered as the condition wasn't met.

```
y = 0
Do While y < 12
    Rng.Offset(0, y + 1).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Rng2.Offset(0, y + 1)
    y = y + 1
Loop
```

Really though, for a loop this simple, a `For` loop will always be easier to diagnose than a `Do` loop...

```
For y = 0 to 11
    Rng.Offset(0, y + 1).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Rng2.Offset(0, y + 1)
Next y
```

Comment: thanks! your advice really helped alot. the code is working now!